# How To Apply Custom Shipping Tax Amount in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We need to apply a **custom shipping tax rate** to the shipping amount. Present i configured flat `12% tax on shipping prices` but i need to take highest tax percentage from all the products in `cart/checkout` and needs to apply it.

For example in my cart page i have `two products` which is under following tax rules.

```
Product A - 5% tax

Product B - 12% tax
```

In this case i need to take `12% tax` and added it to the shipping amount. How can i proceed on this?

Comment: Can anybody help me on this?